# Bypass Triggers

Tags: trigger

Is there a simple line of code to Bypass all triggers in an Object?

I have an apex class on Opportunity and need to Bypass all Triggers in lead Object with an easy line of code. Need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @TusharSharma answer. Do this in a Utility Class. You can then use the Utility class to turn various settings in your org "on" and "off" at will. Below is a good example of what I'm speaking of that includes many examples of utilities that some might find helpful, including the kind of boolean variables you could use.

This code was primarily used for turning portions of code on and off during testing, controlling recursion in triggers (BTW, boolean variables used for that purpose should generally not be static), and to limit the number of times a class could run without exceeding API limits. As you can see, its a number of years old. However, the principles used in it would apply to your situation and with slight modifications could be used for other purposes as well.

```
/*============================================================
* Apex Code Patrol, 2011
*
* http://code.google.com/p/apex-code-patrol/
*
* Code is licensed under "New BSD License".
*============================================================
*/
/**
* ApexCodePatrol
* allows you to control the execution of your classes, triggers, groups or even single methods,
* by setting execution limits or simply disabling the code on the fly. Additionally
*/
global class ApexCodePatrol {


static Map<String,Ponch> officers;

/**
*============================================================
* GLOBAL FLAGS / CONTEXT
*
* eval Pages, Triggers, Tests and Async
*============================================================
*/

// VISUALFORCE CONTEXT
global static Boolean isPage(){
return ApexPages.currentPage() != null;
}

// TRIGGER CONTEXT
global static Boolean isTrigger(){
return Trigger.isExecuting;
}

// TEST CONTEXT
global static Boolean isTest(){
return Test.isRunningTest();
}

// ASYNC CONTEXT
/**
* True if we haven't reached the futures limit
*/
global static Boolean allowFutureCall(){
return remainingFutureCalls() > 0;
}
/**
* Diff. between LimitFutureCalls and acutall number of calls made
*/
global static Integer remainingFutureCalls(){
return Limits.getLimitFutureCalls() - Limits.getFutureCalls();
}

/**
*============================================================
* EXECUTION CONTROL
*============================================================
*/

/**
* Register code and the max. executions
*/
global static void register(String key, Integer numberOfExecutions){
getOfficer(key,numberOfExecutions);
}

/**
* Returns true if you can execute your code and increments the execution counter.
* To simplly eval if you can execute a certain code use canExecute() method instead
*/
global static Boolean execute(String key, Integer maxExecutions){
Ponch off = getOfficer(key,maxExecutions);
// reset the limit's when executed in testMode for the first time
if(off.isTestMode() && off.getCounter() == 0){
off.resetLimits(maxExecutions);
}
return getOfficer(key,maxExecutions).execute();
}

/**
* sames as above, but sets number of executions 1 one
*/
global static Boolean execute(String key){
return execute(key,1);
}

/**
* Start and stop tests for parts of your code, to evaluate testMode use isTest(String)
* for a sample see inlcuded unitTests
* In general you should use system.isRunningTest() or isTest()
*/
global static void startTest(String key){
getOfficer(key,0).setTestMode(true);
}

global static void stopTest(String key){
getOfficer(key,0).setTestMode(false);
}

/**
* Disable code for execution
*/
global static void disable(String key){
getOfficer(key).setDisabled(true);
}

/**
* Enable code for execution
*/
global static void enable(String key){
getOfficer(key).setDisabled(false);
}

/**
*============================================================
* COUNTER AND LIMITS
*============================================================
*/
/**
* Return the number of executions of a code
*/
global static Integer getCounter(String key){
return getOfficer(key).getCounter();
}

/**
* Returns the execution limit of a code
*/
global static Integer getLimit(String key){
return getOfficer(key).getLimit();
}

/**
* Sets the counter for code matching the key param to 0 and overwrites the limits
*/
global static void resetLimits(String key, Integer maxExecutions){
getOfficer(key).resetLimits(maxExecutions);
}


/**
*============================================================
* CONCRETE FLAGS
*============================================================
*/
/**
* Evals if a code can be executed
*/
global static Boolean canExecute(String key){
return getOfficer(key).canExecute();
}
/**
* Evals if execution is blocked by any code which key is contained in keys set param
*/
global static Boolean canExecute(Set<String> keys){

for(String key : keys){
if(isRegistered(key) && !canExecute(key))
return false;
}
return true;
}
/**
* True if code has been disabled
*/
global static Boolean isDisabled(String key){
return getOfficer(key).isDisabled();
}

/**
* True if startTest(String) has been called
*/
global static Boolean isTest(String key){
return getOfficer(key).isTestMode();
}
/**
* Evals if there's an officer keep track of the code
*/
global static Boolean isRegistered(String key){
return getOfficers().containsKey(key);
}


/**
*============================================================
* HELPER UTILS
*============================================================
*/
private static Map<String,Ponch> getOfficers(){
if(officers == null){
officers = new Map<String,Ponch>();
}
return officers;
}

/**
* Returns an the officer matching key, if it does not exist an new one is created
*/
private static Ponch getOfficer(String key){
return getOfficer(key,1);
}

private static Ponch getOfficer(String key, Integer maxExecutions){

if(!isRegistered(key)){
officers.put(key,new Ponch(key,maxExecutions));
}
return getOfficers().get(key);
}


/**
* THE OFFICER
*
* Every code controlled by the ApexCodePatrol has its personal Erik,
* who knows their names and ensures that they stay within their limits.
*/
public class Ponch {

String name;

Integer exeLimit;
Integer exeCounter;

// FLAGS
Boolean inTestMode;
Boolean disabled;

/**
* Class constructor, defines the name and max. number of executions
*/
public Ponch(String Pname, Integer maxExecutions){
name = Pname;
resetLimits(maxExecutions);
inTestMode = false;
disabled = false;
}

/**
* set the inTestMode flag
*/
public void setTestMode(Boolean testMode){
inTestMode = testMode;
}

public Boolean isTestMode(){
return inTestMode;
}

/**
* Disable / enable the code
*/
public void setDisabled(Boolean disable){
disabled = disable;
}
/**
* True if code has been disabled
*/
public Boolean isDisabled(){
return disabled;
}

/**
* The number of time execute() has been called
*/
public Integer getCounter(){
return exeCounter < exeLimit ? exeCounter : exeLimit;
}

/**
* Maximum number of executions for the code
*/
public Integer getLimit(){
return exeLimit;
}

/**
* Call the overwrite the Limit and to set the counter to 0
*/
public void resetLimits(Integer maxExecutions){
exeLimit = maxExecutions;
exeCounter = 0;
}


/**
* Evals if the code can be executed
*/
public Boolean canExecute(){
return (exeLimit > exeCounter || exeLimit == 0 && inTestMode) && !disabled;
}

/**
* Returns true if the code can be executed and increments the counter
*/
public Boolean execute(){
if(!canExecute()) return false;

exeCounter++;
return true;
}
}
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
Public class Test_ApexCodePatrol {

/**
* Dedicated Test Class
*
*/


private static testMethod void testCore(){
// imaginary code names
string cls1 = 'AccountHierarchy';
string mtd1 = 'AccountHierarchy.build()';
string trg1 = 'AccountTriggerBefore';

// GLOBAL FLAGS

// system.assertEquals(false,ApexCodePatrol.isPage()); --> fails
// isPage() not necessarily false, even when running the test in IDE it evals to true
// verfied that it worked via trigger and api
// system.debug(ApexPages.currentPage()) prints out==> System.PageReference[null];
system.assertEquals(ApexPages.currentPage() != null,ApexCodePatrol.isPage());
system.assertEquals(false,ApexCodePatrol.isTrigger());
system.assertEquals(true,ApexCodePatrol.isTest());

// ACP Tests
ApexCodePatrol.startTest(cls1);
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.isTest(cls1));
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.isRegistered(cls1));

// since it hasn't been executed the class should be executable able at least once
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.canExecute(cls1));

// same goes for sets
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.canExecute(new Set<String>{cls1,'no_block'}));

// DISABLE TRIGGER
// before executing the class, disable the account trigger,in order to perform a dml operation
// that causes a recrusive trigger
ApexCodePatrol.disable(trg1);
system.assertNotEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.canExecute(new Set<String>{trg1,'no_block'}));
system.assertEquals(false, ApexCodePatrol.execute(trg1));
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.isDisabled(trg1));
system.assertEquals(0, ApexCodePatrol.getCounter(trg1));

// EXECUTE CLASS
// Excute the class for the first time
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.execute(cls1));
system.debug('\n**counter=' + ApexCodePatrol.getCounter(cls1) + '\n limit' + ApexCodePatrol.getLimit(cls1));
// at the second attempt it's false because no MaxExecutions has been defined
system.assertEquals(false, ApexCodePatrol.canExecute(cls1));
system.assertEquals(ApexCodePatrol.getCounter(cls1),ApexCodePatrol.getLimit(cls1));

// to build the hierarchy, buildMethod needs to be executed 10, times
// in order to reach 100% test coverage use register instead of inline defintion
ApexCodePatrol.register(mtd1, 10);
for(integer i = 0; i<10;i++){
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.execute(mtd1));
}
system.assertEquals(false, ApexCodePatrol.canExecute(mtd1));
// reset the limit for the method to 1
ApexCodePatrol.resetLimits(mtd1, 1);
system.assertEquals(true, ApexCodePatrol.canExecute(mtd1));

// ENABLE & EXECUTE TRIGGER
ApexCodePatrol.enable(trg1);
system.assertEquals(false,ApexCodePatrol.isDisabled(trg1));
system.assertEquals(true,ApexCodePatrol.execute(trg1));

// Finsh the Test
ApexCodePatrol.stopTest(cls1);
system.assertEquals(false,ApexCodePatrol.isTest(cls1));
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use custom settings to put the true/false values and refer this value in each trigger ( at the top of the triggers ). **If the value in the custom setting is true and the user is a DM user** then simply return from the trigger. Something like this :

```
trigger OpptyTrigger_BeforeInsert on Opportunity ( Before Insert ){
    Boolean bypassTrigger = // get value from custom setting
    Id currentUserId = // get value from custom setting

    if(bypassTrigger && currentUserId == UserInfo.getUserId()){
      return;
    }

    // trigger logic here ...

}
```

But you will have to put this block in each existing trigger  and whenever you create new triggers.

----------- EDIT ------------------

The advantage of putting the values in the custom setting is you can turn bypassing on / off just by changing the value in the custom setting without changing the code.

Comment: This could potentially cause unwanted side effects though. If your transaction is a long running one, then anyone else who starts a new transaction will also bypass the triggers.....Just something to consider

Comment: @Eric - Thanks for the point you raised - but the OP had asked for a small snippet with which he could do this. One could always extend this solution to include such scenarios. For example, if data    migration or bypassing is a daily activity then we can have another field in the custom setting called UserId - this user will be a dedicated DM user - and check that with the current running user as well .. I have edited the code accordingly to address this concern.

Answer (score 2):

create a static variable and set it true. When you want to bypass filter then set it to false. and in the trigger check this variable if it is false then don't run the trigger.